# Do the people that sold naked calls that expire in the money have to settle up at the closing price on the day of expiry?

Tags: stocks, options, stock-markets, call-options

If a naked call expires Friday does the issuer of that call have to pay the 4:00 Friday price for the 100 shares or can they wait for a better price after hours, or the next day before settling?

Comment: Don't they have to pay in *stocks*, not money?

Comment: @user253751 I guess the question is - can they wait hours or days after 4:00 Friday to acquire the stocks and settle up?

Comment: @user253751 - Yes, for an American style option (equities), you have to deliver the shares to satisfy the exercise/assignment. European options (most indexes) are settled in cash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long call gives the owner the right to buy the stock at the strike price.  As the seller, you are obligated to sell the underlying at the strike price.

If your short call expires in-the-money, you must deliver the shares if you own them.  If you do not own them and if they are available, your broker will borrow them from another account and deliver them to the exerciser of the call.  You will then be short the shares.  If the shares are not borrowable, your broker will buy them for you on the open market (after hours) so that you can satisfy the assignment.

There is no involvement on your part with waiting for `a better price after hours, or the next day before settling.` This is all handled automatically  by the OCC and your broker.